# Apigee installation on Gke & EKS

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, apigee

I am pretty new to apigee platform.. I am planning to setup apigee hybrid on both gke and eks clusters as I have applications on both.. want to know how apigee can be setup as a unified gateway for both the clusters..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the Apigee Hybrid runtime in each Kubernetes cluster (both GKE and EKS). This includes deploying the runtime components and configuring them to connect to your organization on the Apigee control plane. The installation and configuration steps are similar for both GKE and EKS. Here is a documentation as guidance. [1] You may use the Apigee control plane to manage your APIs regardless of where they are deployed. Also, this includes tasks such as creating and configuring API products, developer apps, and developer portals
[1] https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/hybrid/support-d